# make edit grow and shrink dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

Let's say I have a simple `EditText` and a button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".DebugSimpleActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:hint="Type here"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
        android:singleLine="false" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnParse"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="parse"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/input" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This will look something like this:

[image]

And typing in the `EditText` will expand that editable text field until finally it no longer fits on the screen, at which point it will start scrolling.

There are two things I'd like to change about that behaviour:

- stop expanding when doing so would result in the button's being pushed off-screen
- don't gradually expand, immediately jump to the largest possible size

I.e. I want an `EditText` that starts this big

[image]

but as soon as you start typing, shrinks as much as is necessary to show the button.

[image]

Is there a way to achieve such a behaviour?

Comment: Try to change the `EditText` `layout_height` to a specified value in dp instead of `wrap_content`.

Comment: @Azhy that would make me have to guess at the correct dp value depending on the device the app is running on.

Comment: it's not a big problem, you can use something like `300dp` i think there's no more devices that there screen is smaller than that size and if you dont want that just confgure the editText size from the code using screen size to fit from it.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this, hope this helps you.

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/xValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="xValue" />
```

Comment: uh ... it's an ``EditText``, alright. Beyond that it doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer although may be you don't need these changes but i think this is the best answer, first you should put the `Button` to above the `EditText` and create a drawable resource names Border.xml and some other changes to create a nice layout:-

> Layout.xml

```
...

<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnParse"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:text="parse"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

...

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/input"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:hint="Type here"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
    android:singleLine="false"        
    android:background="@drawable/Border" />

...
```

---

> Border.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" ><solid android:color="@android:color/white" /><stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#4fa5d5"/></shape>
```

Comment: All this does is make the background white. I also do not want to put the buttons above the text but rather keep them at the bottom, close to the keyboard for easier access. So if I set `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`` the buttons are pushed off the screen again.